# How to fetch data from salesforce custom object using SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, controller

Below in `eventDates` method I tried to fetch the `Event.eventDates__c` but it didn't work. It isn't assigning the `Event__c` type to `String[]`. Anyhow I only need the dates from this field in the form of an array which I have to pass to a JS array. Any help please.

```
public with sharing class EventsPageController {

    public String datesFromCalendar {get; set;}
    public List<String> eachDt = new List<String>();

    public void EventsPageController() {
        Event = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c,Event_Description__c,Event_Type__c,Maximum_Attendees__c,Occurrence__c,Program_Name__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    }

    public Event__c getEvent(){
        return Event;
    }

    public String[] eventDates(){
        //String[] EventDates = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        return string[] = Event.EventDates__c;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**In this line,**

```
String[] EventDates = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

You are trying to assign a list of custom objects, `Event__c`, to a list of Strings.  This is likely why you are getting the error.  Normally, I would say you would want to try instead retrieving a list of Event__c objects, and looping through and assigning the EventDates__c field (assuming the field type is in fact, a string) to your list of strings.  It looks like though this is a controller for a page where you pass the ID of the specific event object you want to work with, so you don't really have to worry about a list.  I would change the whole class a bit so you are retrieving and assigning the Event object in the constructor and then you can access it in your method.  Something like below

```
public with sharing class EventsPageController {

    Event__c e                          {get; set;}
    public String datesFromCalendar     {get; set;}
    public List<String> eachDt = new List<String>();

    public void EventsPageController() {
        e = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c,Event_Description__c,Event_Type__c,Maximum_Attendees__c,Occurrence__c,Program_Name__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public Event__c getEvent(){
        return Event;
    }

    public String eventDates(){
        String EventDates = e.EvenDates__c;
        return EventDates;
    }
}
```

If the EventDates__c field contains more than one date in the string and you are trying to seperate them and return them in a list of strings, this can be done using the join function, but this requires that you are using a separator in the field.  Let's assume you are using a ';' as a separator.  Then you could use something like this

```
public list<string> eventDates(){

     list<String> EventDates = new list<String>();
     EventDates = e.EventDates__c.split(';');
     return EventDates;

}
```

You can obviously adjust this if you want to use a different seperator like a space or a comma.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry to add something more that wasn't been asked in the original question. Actually in the next step I want these dates to be pushed in a JS array. I'm not getting the use of `<apex:repeat>` to push this array to JS array. It will be great if you can explain it too. I'll change my question accordingly so that it can be helpful for other. Thanks.

Comment: I can help with that but I really would add that as a second question.  When you start combining multiple and complex questions, it becomes harder for people to find help when they have a similar issue.

Comment: Ok let me create another question and do I post the link to question in comments here? If you don't mind.

Comment: [Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63675/how-to-pass-an-array-of-strings-to-javascript-array-from-apex-controller)