# How to pass an array of strings to JavaScript array from Apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

How can I pass an array of strings `EventDates` from method `public String[] eventDates()` to the JavaScript array in my visualforce page? `datesFromCalendar` holds an array of dates coming from JavaScript and saved in salesforce in TextArea(Long). Now I want to send them back to JavaScript array. Any ideas?

```
public with sharing class EventsPageController {
    public Event__c Event{ 
     get {
      if (Event == null)
        Event = new Event__c();
      return Event;
    }
    set;
  }
    public String datesFromCalendar {get; set;}
    public List<String> eachDt = new List<String>();

    public void EventsPageController() {
        Event = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c,Event_Description__c,Event_Type__c,Maximum_Attendees__c,Occurrence__c,Program_Name__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    }

    public Event__c getEvent(){
        return Event;
    }

    public String[] eventDates(){

      list<String> EventDates = new list<String>();
      list<Event__c> eventList = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

      for(Event__c event : eventList) {
           EventDates.add(event.EventDates__c);
      }
      return EventDates;
}

    public PageReference saveData(){
        System.debug(datesFromCalendar);            
        try {
            Event.EventDates__c = datesFromCalendar;
            upsert(Event);
        } catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        // After Save, navigate to the default view page:
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(Event)).view(); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 ways you can do that.

**Method 1**

First change the method to a getter method

```
public String[] geteventDates(){

      //your code
      return EventDates;
}
```

and then you can access in javascript something like this

```
<script>
 <apex:repeat value="{!eventDates}" var="event">
        console.log('the event is ==  {!event}');
    </apex:repeat>
</script>
```

**Method 2**

Serialize the `List<String>` using the `JSON.serialize()` and then use the `JSON.parse()` in the VF.

```
public String geteventDates(){

      //your code
      return JSON.serialize(EventDates);
}
```

in you VF:

```
var stringArray = JSON.parse('{!eventDates}');
for(var i=0;i<stringArray.length;i++) {
   console.log('The event is == '+ stringArray[i]);
}
```

**Method 3**

You can also use JS remoting. You can read about it [here](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm). But you cannot access instance variables in remoting methods. So you have to make the call which one you have to use.

Comment: This is what I get with the JSON method.
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ap1.salesforce.com/_ui/common/request/servlet/JsLoggingServlet. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: @Superman: AFAIK that error has nothing to do with which method you use. these are some internal salesforce issue

Comment: You explained all the methods very well. And I just got understanding each of them. Unfortunately I don't get any of them work with my code. Possibly there will be some issues at my end.  Please have a look the way I'm trying to use it in my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Superman/oekfhotg/).

Comment: Related to above comment. I'm getting the empty array.

Comment: Since you've already accepted this answer I assume that all your issues were resolved. If not then try isolating the code and see where the issue is.

Comment: The method 2 will not work if the string contains special characters. For example: "," and "\"